# How to create two button for progress dialog?

Tags: android, button, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog with under code :

```
 ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,
                    "Hide",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            pDialog.show();
```

I want to create two button for progrss dialog,how to create two button for progress dialog ?

Comment: can you explain exactly which view exactly does you need.

Comment: I have a progress dialog with hide button,I need one elso button for cancle

Answer (score 0):

We can to create two button for ProgressDialog with under code :

```
    ProgressDialog myDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    myDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    myDialog.setCancelable(false);
    myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // your code
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
```